# Get value of sin(x)

Tags: trigonometry

I need help with trigonometry:

How can I calculate $\alpha$: $$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ ? I can't find value of this angle in any table...

Comment: I just want to be sure the negative is inside the root?

Comment: Have you seen sin defined in terms of exponentials?

Comment: I see you edited it where the negative is outside the root. You should be able to whip out your unit circle and find in the 3rd and 4th quadrant that the sine value is $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for $\alpha=\frac{ 5 \pi}{4} , \frac{ 7 \pi}{4}$

Comment: $\alpha = -45^\circ = -\pi/4$ wont do?

Comment: @randomgirl Typo error in nominator. Sorry for that. 

GeorgeMoore no, sorry.

Comment: See picture. https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/images/circle-unit-radians.gif

Comment: @user229518 don't worry then, that was for if the minus was inside! If you're not quite liking the geometrical way of looking at it, think $sin(-x) = -sin(x)$

Comment: I kinda wanna see it solved for with the negative in the root actually. That sounds like it could be fun.

Comment: @user229518 do you see it on the table now?

Comment: Yeah, I thought that there was a faster way to calculate it. I drew that angle on x0y, calculated $\sin(\frac{-\sqrt(2)}{2})$, changed sign, summed quarter and got $\frac{5\pi}{4}$. Thank you all for help :)

Comment: Its so much easier to forget about the unit circle and just use any circle. We have
$$\sin\alpha=\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
so just use the denominator as the radius (i.e. hypotenuse) and the numerator as the opposite side. Using the Pythagorean theorem we can find the adjacent side and note that its magnitude is equal to the magnitude of the opposite side (if you don't recognize this as a special triangle yet, try drawing a diagram). This lets us conclude that the angle is $1/8$ of a rotation, albeit negative (i.e. $-\pi/4$).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\sin \alpha =  -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \iff \sin(-\alpha) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
The positive angle $-\alpha$ can be found in the triangle given by the end points $A=(0,0)$, $B=(0,1)$ and $C=(1,0)$. As the angle $-\alpha = \pi/4$.
Thus $\alpha = -\pi/4 = 2\pi - \pi/4 = 7\pi/4$.

And from
$$
\sin(\alpha + \pi) = -\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \Rightarrow \\
\alpha + \pi = \pi/4 \Rightarrow 
\alpha = \pi/4 - \pi = -3\pi/4 = 2 \pi -3\pi/4 = 5\pi/4
$$

**Bonus:**

$$
\sin \alpha =  \frac{\sqrt{-2}}{2}
$$

That is only possible in the complex domain:
$$
\sin z = i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
$$
and
$$
\sin(-iu) = \sinh(u) / i 
$$
this gives
$$
\sinh u = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\Rightarrow 
u = - \sinh^{-1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
\Rightarrow
z = i \sinh^{-1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}
$$
where $\sinh^{-1}(1/\sqrt{2}) = 0.658478..$.

Adding the periodicity of $\sin(z) = \sin(z + 2\pi k)$ it should be
$$
z = 2\pi k + i \sinh^{-1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})
$$
And using the symmetry $\sin(z) = - \sin(z + \pi)$ we get
$$
z = 2\pi k + \pi - i \sinh^{-1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})
$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%3Dsqrt%28-2%29%2F2 wolfram gives another solution $z=2 \pi k+\pi-i \sinh^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ I guess we can get this solution in a similar way maybe.

Comment: There is also a third quadrant solution to the intended problem.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I overlooked a symmetry again it seems.